# Applications List

Tags: facebook-apps

Is there a way to get a list of all public Facebook applications and some associated data with them such as category, id, title, description, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can info on an individual application by using the Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

You might also be able to use FQL to get a list of applications:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/

Comment: It doesn't look like I can use FQL because of the index requirement in the query.